# Conveying Emotion in Non-audible and audible sounds

Tags: sound-design, emotion

I have been working on this short film for a couple weeks now.

The plot of the short film is a guy waking up on the beach, having no idea of where he is at or how he got there (he was shipwrecked). There is no one around him, mostly all we see is the beach; Sand and water.

I was wondering if there is a way to evoke and/or convey emotions of not knowing of where he is by sound design.

My second question, is it possible to also do this with non-audible sounds or very low volume audio to convey emotions. An answer to both would be great so I can use them together.

So far, I have the ambience around him like wind, waves, and ocean sounds pretty lound in the mix so it feels like he is almost overwhelmed and cofused. Further opinions would be apprieciated! -Thanks

Comment: Watch first 20 minutes of Never Cry Wolf. Really good sound

Comment: What do you mean by non-audible sounds?  If it isn't audible, it doesn't do anything and likely won't play back in most cases anyway.

Comment: I mean it can be faint or low in volume but it wouldn't be a major sound. I've been watching alot of horror lately and there are some soft floorboard creaks before something happens. Most of the time I'd think this would go un-notice and would just be added to evoke more  fear or a que to know something is coming up. (By the way, I am new to this)

Comment: You can follow this approach but be very careful about not to turn the movie into a cartoon. There is a very thin line in between that you may never notice you are on the other side.